# WHERE is NULL clause returning NON NULL Values

Tags: sql, oracle

This is baffling to me. I have the following query:

```
SELECT *
  FROM table.contract
 WHERE end_date IS NULL
   AND LOWER(NAME) LIKE 'name'
    OR LOWER(NAME) LIKE '%name1%'
    OR LOWER(NAME) LIKE '%name2%'
```

As it should be, it should only return rows where the END_DATE is NULL, but I'm getting rows that have a date in them.

The data type is DATE and the data default is (null) so I have no idea why it's returning some rows with dates as well. Am I just having a brain fart? It is Friday so I apologize if I'm missing something simple.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: I am quite an idiot. I forgot my parenthesis, the code should be as follows:

```
SELECT *
  FROM table.contract
 WHERE end_date IS NULL
   AND (LOWER(NAME) LIKE 'name'
    OR LOWER(NAME) LIKE '%name1%'
    OR LOWER(NAME) LIKE '%name2%')
```

Comment: You might be interested in operator precedence

Comment: You have an OR in your filter list. I imagine you meant to use parenthesis somewhere.

Comment: A hint: What is the difference between 1+1*8 and (1+1) * 8?

Comment: Although it's a rather "stupid" mistake, I don't get why people downvote this question. Upvoted for counter balance. The answer is already given in the comments above.

Comment: @Mihai... I'm unbelieveable... I forgot my parenthesis around the lower(name)s.... that's embarassing... Like I said... it's Friday after a long week hahaha..

Comment: @HepC Yep... can't believe my stupidity hahaha

Comment: @dfundako yes... completely idiotic on my end...

Comment: @Jens I appreciate the counter balance.. but I don't blame them.. that was extremely stupid on my end hahaha

Comment: @dfundako Good one! ;)

Comment: @Kumar_Vikas agreed... good explanation..

Comment: can you give us the row you getting that have a date in them.

Answer (score 1):

you appear to be missing  some () to ensure the correct precendence between your "AND"s and your "OR"s.

eg

```
SELECT *
  FROM table.contract
 WHERE end_date IS NULL
   AND (LOWER(NAME) LIKE 'name'
    OR LOWER(NAME) LIKE '%name1%'
    OR LOWER(NAME) LIKE '%name2%')
```